# What does Friedrichs mean by "Myriotic fields"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

I came across K. O. Friedrichs' very old book (1953) "Mathematical Apsects of the Quantum Theory of Fields", and hardly any of it makes sense to me.

One of the strange things that he refers to are "Myriotic" fields.  What are these?  Is there a modern account of what Friedrichs is talking about?

Comment: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/myriotic+field

Comment: This seems a little strange... any further details on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty imprecise answer, because I haven't heard the term in a long time. I think (someone please correct me if this is wrong) a "myriotic" field is one in which there are an infinite number of quanta, so you don't have a well-defined notion of number operator or vacuum state.